# Invalid JSON response for Table refresh

Tags: jquery, json, jakarta-ee, datatable

I want to make my refresh my table dynamically, in order to make it i sent some parameters to the Servlet, the Servelt return excatly what i want ( a List) but the problem comes when i have to refresh. I share my code:

Servelt (working no problem) :

```
System.out.println("ligne ="+lignes);
String lignes= request.getParameter("lignes");
        String numero= request.getParameter("process");
        List<String> LigneAvant = EquilibrageTableOperationService.findAllAvantWithParameters(lignes,numero);
        String json = new Gson().toJson(LigneAvant); 
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Table (working no problem ) :

```
<table id="tableAvant" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
 <thead>
 <tr>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Ordre</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Nom Pross</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Verbe</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Nom Op</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Mini</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Maxi</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Tps Total</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Tps Mesure</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Tps Retour</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">TDA</div></th>
     <th style="display:none"><div class="rotate ">Tps Total</div></th>
     <th style="display:none"><div class="rotate ">Tps Mesure</div></th>
     <th style="display:none"><div class="rotate ">Tps Retour</div></th>
     <th style="display:none"><div class="rotate ">TDA</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">% Opera</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Loc Avant</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr th:each="LIST : ${LigneAvant}">
    <td  th:text="${LIST[0]}" ></td>
    <td th:text="${LIST[1]}" ></td>
    <td  th:text="${LIST[2]}" ></td>
    <td th:text="${LIST[3]}" ></td> 
    <td  th:text="${LIST[4]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[5]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[6]}" ></td>    
    <td  class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[7]}" ></td>
    <td  class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[8]}" ></td>
    <td  class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[9]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[10]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[11]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[12]}" ></td>
    <td style="display:none" th:text="${LIST[13]}" ></td>   
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[14]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[15]}" ></td>   
     </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

and finally my jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).on("change", "#process", function() {  // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
    var process=$('#process').val();
    var lignes=$('#lignes').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url : "/tps_assy-web/equilibrageReloadTableOperation",
        data:{lignes: lignes, process: process},
        success: function(json){  
            $("#tableAvant").dataTable().fnClearTable();
            $("#tableAvant").dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#tableAvant').DataTable(json).ajax.reload(null, false);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The problem is coming by

```
$('#tableAvant').DataTable(json).ajax.reload(null, false);
```

This return :"Invalid JSON response.", i tested the Json response with https://jsonlint.com/ and my json is totally valid !!!
I have no clue where the error is, can you help me please ?

Comment: Check the raw response in devtools to maks sure there isn't something extra before or after the JSON.

Comment: In devtool, before and after the JSON, response is good, i also checked on [link](https://jsonlint.com/)  and the json is valid, i have no clue why i have this error ...

Comment: Maybe it's valid JSON but not organized properly for what `DataTable` needs.